# Why QProgressDialog is shown without an explicit call to `exec()` or `show()`?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have the following code

```cpp
#include "dialog.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QProgressDialog>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QProgressDialog w;
    //w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

The execution of this code shows a QProgressDialog UI.

[image]

I would like to have the explanation why my QProgressDialog shows up without having an `exec()`or `show()` instructions.
I have read the documentation but did not find the explanation on it.

Comment: I think it's intended behavior of `QProgressDialog`. It shows/hides automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both constructors of [`QProgressDialog`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/dialogs/qprogressdialog.cpp.html#_ZN15QProgressDialogC1EP7QWidget6QFlagsIN2Qt10WindowTypeEE) call [`QProgressDialogPrivate::init`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/dialogs/qprogressdialog.cpp.html#_ZN22QProgressDialogPrivate4initERK7QStringS2_ii), where `forceTimer : QTimer` is started:

```
 ...
 forceTimer = new QTimer(q);
 QObject::connect(forceTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), q, SLOT(forceShow()));
 ...
 forceTimer->start(showTime);
```

The [`forceShow()`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/dialogs/qprogressdialog.cpp.html#_ZN15QProgressDialog9forceShowEv) slot in turn looks like this:

```
void QProgressDialog::forceShow() {
    Q_D(QProgressDialog);
    d->forceTimer->stop();
    if (d->shown_once || d->cancellation_flag)
        return;
    show();
    d->shown_once = true;
}
```

The `show();` statement there is the very reason the `QProgressDialog` is shown on object creation.

Answer (score 1):

Since it will automatically open after being constructed, follow it with a cancellation.

```
auto * progressDialog = new QProgressDialog{};
progressDialog.cancel();
```